# Do INotifyPropertyChanged notifies only the changes from the user interface

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, view, inotifypropertychanged

Do INotifyPropertyChanged notifies only the changes from the user interface. And in other means we can also say that the changes to value of the properties from other sources then the user interface are not notified ?

Comment: No, INotifyPropertyChanged has nothing to with notifications FROM the user interface. Bindings take care of that, in response to dependency property change notifications, which do not use INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed. So it assure the Notify between the UI and the source, if you want the notification be two way, you have to set the binding mode to `TwoWay` so the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Notify the changed from the User Interface only if you set the binding mode to `OneWay` To source, if you set the Binding `TwoWay` so the notify will be from the UI to the source and from the source to the UI.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged has nothing to do with the UI notifying the binding source of changes. It's only used for the source to notify the target. Mode=TwoWay does cause the Binding to update the source property, but not via INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Please refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually I change the value of a hashset from an ICommand inherited class.
I want to ask that would this change be notified by the OnPropertyChanged in the getter of the Property.

public HashSet<Deduction> EmpDeductions
        {
            get { return empDeductions; }
            set
            {
                if(empDeductions != value)
                {
                    empDeductions = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("EmpDeductions");
                    NetSalary = NetSalary;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @SyedKumailHaiderNaqvi you should edit your question and post some code to get what you want exactly.